# Creating JSON object from DB results to post back into jquery UI Dialog, using ajax post method

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I have a script that loads sample images from DB on page load from relevant category in the DB.

```
<?php
$category = 'granite'; 
$samples = 'SELECT * FROM material WHERE material_type = :cat';
$res = $db->prepare($samples);
$res->execute(array(':cat' => $category));
$count = $res->rowCount();
if($count > 0) 
while ($row = $res -> fetch()){
    $postimggranite = $row[mat_image];
    $postidgranite = $row[id];
?>
<?php
    echo "<div class='sample'>";
    echo "<h3 class='sample_h'>$row[name]</h3>";
    echo "<a href='/images/granite-worktops/samples/$postimggranite'><img src='/images/granite-worktops/thumbs/$postimggranite' alt='$row[name]' width='100' height='100' class='aligncenter size-full' title='$row[name]'></a>";
    echo "<br /><a class=\"button\" href=\" \" rel=\"nofollow\" onClick=\"user_notice(this,''); return false;\">More Details</a>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

As you can see from the script above in the last echo before closing a div I have a "More Details button, by clicking on which the dialog appears on the screen where I need to display additional information from the same DB. Method I am planning to use is

```
function user_dialog(a,b){
    "undefined"!=typeof jQuery.ui?($("#dialog").attr("title","Detailed Information").html(a),
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal:true,
        width:400,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Download: function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    window.location=b
                    }
                    }
                    }
                    ))
                    :window.location=b}

function user_notice(a){
    download_link=$(a).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/includes/json.php",
        data:"action=reminder&thepath="+download_link,
        dataType:"json",
        error:function(){
            window.location=download_link
            },
        success:function(a){
            1==a.status&&user_dialog(a.html,download_link);
            }
            })
            };
```

Here also the script of my json.php file

```
<?php
header('X-Robots-Tag: noindex, noarchive');
$a = session_id();
if(empty($a)) session_start();
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']){

  $resp_dialog = array(
    'status' => 1,
    'html' => '<p>Here is you sample and rest of staff</p>'
  );
  echo json_encode($resp_dialog);
  }else{
      header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
      exit;
      }
?>
```

clearly it all works and the line `<p>Here is you sample and rest of staff</p>` is appearing in the dialog, but what I actually need is to create a json object that brings additional info from DB and have no idea where, inside the `json.php` file or create some sort of additional file and place in href with `urlid="something to get fromdb"` than `$_GET['urlid']` in the `json.php` to send it do DB. Basically have no idea of what and where to do it.

Please go easy on me since I am still learning this all and most of it is still pretty new for me, so forgive me if I have not explained something correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in your $.ajax the id of the category you want to detail.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/includes/json.php",
    data:['cat_id': cat_id], // passing var cat_id from the link...
```

Then your json.php file should be like:

```
<?php
header('X-Robots-Tag: noindex, noarchive');
$a = session_id();
if(empty($a)) session_start();
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']){

  $cat_id = $_POST['cat_id']; // Grab the Id of the category you want to detail...

   // Here you have to fetch the info from the DB...
   $samples = '... WHERE cat_id = :cat'; // Create the sql here!
   $res = $db->prepare($samples);
   $res->execute(array(':cat' => $cat_id));
   $count = $res->rowCount();
   $htmlToDisplay = '';
   if($count > 0) 
   while ($row = $res -> fetch()){
    $htmlToDisplay += $row['...']; // format yout output...
  }

  $resp_dialog = array(
    'status' => 1,
    'html' => $htmlToDisplay,
  );
  echo json_encode($resp_dialog);
  }else{
      header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
      exit;
      }
?>
```

**Edit:**

To create the "more details" link, try to do this:

```
echo "<div class='sample'>";
/* ... */
// Passing $row[id] to user_notice() function!
echo "<br /><a class=\"button\" onClick=\"user_notice(this,". $row[id] ."); return false;\">More Details</a>";
echo "</div>";
```

And then, change the `user_notice()` function to this:

```
function user_notice(a,cat_id){ // New parameter cat_id!
    download_link=$(a).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/includes/json.php",
        data:{ cat_id: cat_id }, // Passing cat_id to json.php... don't forget to pass your other variables
        /* ... */
```

Look how to pass variables through $.ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: So, basically I have to place DB query script in my json.php, now I get it. Let me try it, I might have to come back if something went wrong. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: I have tried to make it work, but is looks like I can not properly construct the href for More Info button.

Comment: I edited my answer to add how you should pass the id to your json.php file. Then, in that file, grab the id and create your sql.

Comment: here is an error I am getting [15-Apr-2013 10:20:27] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home3/my_domain/public_html/includes/json.php on line 11

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include the db connection in the json.php file. The examples I wrote above are not complete, you must read and change it to suit your needs.

Comment: I have now, but only thing that I can get from db is $row[id], $htmlToDisplay += $row[id]; // format yout output...

Comment: I didn't understand what you said. WHat error/issue do you have now? Look, the examples I wrote above must be changed to suit your needs... your need to code the appropriate sql to fetch the 'extra info' you want to show and then format it to return on a json...

Comment: got it all working just fine, thanks for your help and for standing by

Answer (score 0):

In $.Ajax() function change your passing Data from

```
data:"action=reminder&thepath="+download_link,
```

to

```
data: "{'action':'reminder','thepath':'"+download_link+"'}"
```

Comment: OK, have done it, but not sure if this will help to actually solve my problem

Comment: at the moment I have no errors, but I do not have a script that will send another query to DB to populate json.php that should output the results when dialog is displayed